# Service unavailable message in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have created a sample ASP.NET website and hosted it in IIS 6.0 . It is working fine , if the identity of the defalut app pool is "local system". But when i changed the identity with some other configurable user id then it is showing as "**Service Unavailable**".

The following message is found in the event viewver.

**"The identity of application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is invalid, so the World Wide Web Publishing Service can not create a worker process to serve the application pool.  Therefore, the application pool has been disabled."**

Answer (score 1):

Either the credentials provided for the user is not valid, or the user does not have the needed permissions.

I believe there is a security group on the machine called IIS_WPG that is created when Asp.net is installed, add the user to this group, it should give them the needed permissions.

Comment: In Windows Server 2008/R2, Windows 7 (pro and ultimate) the user group is IIS_IUSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Message is self-explanatory.  The selected user id isn't valid - probably due to insufficient privaledges to run the service.

Answer (score 0):

The user identity you use needs to have fairly significant rights to operate. At a minimum the user needs to have read/execute permission on the root directory of the folder. This user should also have read/write/execute permission on the Temporary Asp.Net Files folder located within the %SystemRoot%/Microsoft.Net/Framework/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

In a development environment you can use the default app pool to create your web applications.

In production environment you want to use lusrmgr.msc (Server 2008/R2/7 Ultimate and Pro) to create new users (and their credentials) on the machine and assign the users to the right group (IIS_IUSRS).

Also once you have created the user, you will want to give it access to your data source back-end (if sql is running on the same machine and using windows authentication to access SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Check Application Pools which assign Site on IIS, probably it is stopped.